# What is the most effective way to refresh a window in pysimplegui

Tags: pysimplegui

Consider the following code:

```
layout = [[sg.Button(key = 'Button')]]
window = sg.Window('window',layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Button':
        function()
```

Here `function()` needs a lot of time to run and the window will therefore "stop responding" if we do not refresh the window. However, the only refresh function I know is `window.refresh()`. Ideally, I want the window to be refreshed frequently enough such that it does not freeze. My attempt is to add it at the very beginning of the event loop so that it refreshes every time the events are read, that is:

```
layout = [[sg.Button(key = 'Button')]]
window = sg.Window('window',layout)
while True:
    window.refresh()
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Button':
        function()
```

But it does not work and the window still freezes when I click the button. How do I keep the window refreshing even if the function is running?

Comment: Try threading.Thread to execute your function or Window.perform_long_operation to automatically run users functions as threads, refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Long_Operations.py

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is indeed threading, with perhaps a loader animation just to say that your program is busy.
This could later be extended with queues to get background task results in realtime.

Install ofunctions.threading module which will be used to decorate your function so it becomes a thread.
`pip install ofunctions.threading`

Here's a working concept of your code:

```py
from ofunctions.threading import threaded, Future

@threaded
def _function():
    # your long running code

def function(*args, **kwargs):
    thread = _function(*args, **kwargs)
    while not thread.done() and not thread.cancelled():
        sg.PopupAnimated(
            sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF,
            message=_t("main_gui.loading_data_from_repo"),
            time_between_frames=50,
            background_color=GUI_LOADER_COLOR,
            text_color=GUI_LOADER_TEXT_COLOR,
        )
    sg.PopupAnimated(None)
    return thread.result()

layout = [[sg.Button(key = 'Button')]]
window = sg.Window('window',layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Button':
        function()
```